# How to know if user authenticated with Touch ID or passcode?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, touch-id

If you use `kSecAccessControlUserPresence` in `SecItemAdd`, Touch ID falls back on asking the user for their passcode.  Is there a way to detect whether the user used Touch ID vs. their passcode?  (Purely for tracking purposes)

Comment: are you asking if a user uses touch ID / passcode on his iphone lock screen and determine what he used?

Comment: No, when accessing a secure keychain from my app.

Comment: is there way to handle passcode feature?